# Parsing JSON with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The problem is that JSON is in the following format:

```
{"think":{"median":1.24531,"test":6.2342}}
```

This is how the output of the server looks like, when I try to parse it I get errors because the values aren't inside quotes.

Comment: How are you trying to parse it? Could you show us some code? What version of Json.Net are you using? 

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx in the 1st example it yields the JSON in the same format as the one you get from the server, so I doubt there's something wrong in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *doubles* and shouldn't be inside quotes. This works:

```
var str = @"{""think"":{""median"":1.24531,""test"":6.2342}}";
dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
Console.WriteLine((double)dyn.think.median);
```